# Is there anyway to clear python bytecode cache?

Tags: python, cpython

each unit test I'm running is writing python code out to a file, then importing it as a module.  The problem is that the code changes but further import statements don't modify the module.

I think what I need is a way to ether force a reload on a module or clear the internal bytecode cache.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Reimporting modules is tricky to get all the edge cases right. The documentation for [reload](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reload) mentions some of them.  Depending on what you are testing, you *may* be better off by testing the imports with separate invocations of the interpreter by running each via, say, [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html).  It will likely be slower but also likely safer and more accurate testing.

Comment: I liked this solution the best because it allows the tests to be done with different python interpreters too and it is a lot safer (my tests work now!)

Answer (score 4):

Use [`reload()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reload).

> Reload a previously imported module.
>   The argument must be a module object,
>   so it must have been successfully
>   imported before. This is useful if you
>   have edited the module source file
>   using an external editor and want to
>   try out the new version without
>   leaving the Python interpreter. The
>   return value is the module object (the
>   same as the module argument).

However, the module needs to be already loaded. A workaround is to handle the resulting `NameError`:

```
try:
    reload(math)
except NameError:
    import math
```

Comment: However, you can only use reload on a module that has already been loaded.  I tried this approach, however dir() doesn't list  my module as loaded

Answer (score 3):

Write your code to differently-named modules.  Writing new code into an existing file, and trying to import it again will not work well.

Alternatively, you can clobber `sys.modules`.  For example:

```
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # Record sys.modules here so we can restore it in tearDown.
        self.old_modules = dict(sys.modules)

    def tearDown(self):
        # Remove any new modules imported during the test run. This lets us
        # import the same source files for more than one test.
        for m in [m for m in sys.modules if m not in self.old_modules]:
            del sys.modules[m]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a similar situation.
Later on found that the white space indentation technique used matters.
Especially on windows platforms, ensure that a uniform technique is adapted 
throughout the module i.e., either use tab or spaces exclusively.